# How can I list all connected channels in Twilio?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm trying to get a list of all connected channels in Twilio by using the following function:

```
chatClient.getUserChannelDescriptors().then(function(paginator) {
  for (i=0; i<paginator.items.length; i++) {
    var channel = paginator.items[i];
    console.log('Channel: ' + channel.friendlyName);
  }
});
```

But this function always gives "chatClient is not a function" in the console. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How do you get `chatClient`?

Comment: log `chatClient` before calling it and provide it in question also.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/channels